Vue 3 Router issue, no outlet, no displayed content
I have a vue3 application which works perfectly fine when embedding all packages in the directly (locally) in the output bundle.
package.json
 "vue": "^3.4.29",
 "vue-router": "^4.3.3"
....

I wish to utilize externals to decrease my bundle size and load time etc.
I configure rollup with the necessary properties for externals as can be seen below:
{
  "modulePreload": false,
  "chunkSizeWarningLimit": 500,
  "rollupOptions": {
    "external": [
      "@gtm-support/vue-gtm",
      "@microsoft/applicationinsights-core-js",
      "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web",
      "@tailwindcss/typography",
      "@vueuse/components",
      "chart.js",
      "class-variance-authority",
      "clsx",
      "elevio",
      "lodash-es",
      "lucide-vue-next",
      "mapbox-gl",
      "pinia",
      "supercluster",
      "tailwind-merge",
      "tailwind-scrollbar",
      "tailwindcss-animate",
      "vue",
      "vue-router"
    ],
    "output": {
      "paths": {
        "@gtm-support/vue-gtm": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@gtm-support/vue-gtm@^2.2.0/+esm",
        "@microsoft/applicationinsights-core-js": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/applicationinsights-core-js@^3.2.2/+esm",
        "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/applicationinsights-web@^3.2.2/+esm",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tailwindcss/typography@^0.5.13/+esm",
        "@vueuse/components": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vueuse/components@^10.11.0/+esm",
        "chart.js": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4.4.3/+esm",
        "class-variance-authority": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/class-variance-authority@^0.7.0/+esm",
        "clsx": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clsx@^2.1.1/+esm",
        "elevio": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/elevio@^1.3.8/+esm",
        "lodash-es": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@^4.17.21/+esm",
        "lucide-vue-next": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lucide-vue-next@^0.321.0/+esm",
        "mapbox-gl": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mapbox-gl@^3.4.0/+esm",
        "pinia": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pinia@^2.1.7/+esm",
        "supercluster": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/supercluster@^8.0.1/+esm",
        "tailwind-merge": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwind-merge@^2.3.0/+esm",
        "tailwind-scrollbar": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwind-scrollbar@^3.1.0/+esm",
        "tailwindcss-animate": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss-animate@^1.0.7/+esm",
        "vue": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^3.4.29/+esm",
        "vue-router": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@^4.3.3/+esm"
      }
    }
  },
  "treeshake": true
}


I ensure vite resolve.dedupe is specified as below
{
  "dedupe": [
    "@gtm-support/vue-gtm",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-core-js",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web",
    "@tailwindcss/typography",
    "@vueuse/components",
    "chart.js",
    "class-variance-authority",
    "clsx",
    "elevio",
    "lodash-es",
    "lucide-vue-next",
    "mapbox-gl",
    "pinia",
    "supercluster",
    "tailwind-merge",
    "tailwind-scrollbar",
    "tailwindcss-animate",
    "vue",
    "vue-router"
  ]
}


And here is my App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
debugger;
</script>
<template>
  <div class="shrink grow">
      <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
  </div>  
</template>

Unfortunately, when I attempt this everything loads without error yet the vue-router is not rendering any data (the outlet).
In the place where I would see my normal components from the loaded page, I instead see an HTML comment <!----> vnode...
Since this is happening only in the production build when using externals I have difficulty getting the vue debug tools to work in this situation.
Most importantly I find no good reason why the content specified by the router is loaded (I see the chunk load) however the embedded setup method is never called.

Is there any reason why I only see the html comment?
Why is setup never called? (not even a debugger statement is triggered) for example:

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
debugger;
onMounted(()=>{
debugger;
});
</script>

If I remove the externalization of vue-router, everything works as expected.
I am asking this question humbly and seeking any advice on how to debug this issue or what the root cause may be, I don't want to have to unwrap and reverse engineer vue to find out the reason myself but if I cannot find any advice I will have to do the aforementioned.
If you need more information let me know what you would otherwise need and I will provide such.
You can find a minimal viable reproduction of this problem in my repo here
And the official issue I have with the vue project here and with vite here

Not sure about the issue itself sir, but you could check this extension to hack the production build into an inspectable devtools version. Also, consider posting this question on the related Github issues or Discord, maybe even ask it on the Vite one? Good luck debugging this one.

It patches the check successfully but fails to load the dev tools, perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Any errors in the console/network? Btw, try to build it locally maybe? Is it a code or platform issue?

Am building locally btw and no, not a code or platform issue afaik, no console errors etc.

Looks like that extension stopped working on vue2, this is a vue3 app btw.

The extension is supposed to work well for Vue3. Wait, you're building locally but it does not work in production? Do you just build and push to production? So, the code does not work once built and previewed locally? Or does it work fine locally but not once deployed?

It doesn't work locally or in a production like environment but only once externalization is in play, if I simply remove one line from the externals then everything loads correctly (vue-router) in both environments.

FWIW, I found out I could force enable Vuejs.devtools by doing something like this in main.tsx however the debug tools still won't work...
globalThis.VUE_OPTIONS_API = true;
globalThis.VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS = true;

Do you maybe have a public repo for that project that you could share?

Unfortunately not, if I cant figure it out I will see about making a minimal viable reproduction using the latest vue and then submitting an issue in the Vue repo.
Thanks again for your help

Here is a link to the repo, will create an issue asap.
https://github.com/juliusfriedman/vue-project
And the issue -> https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/11172

@Jay As noted in the issue, this looks very specific to using CDN packages. Obscure bugs you're getting may totally be caused by duped packages. Notice that +esm results in from "/npm/vue@3.4.27/+esm" import in vue-router, this looks like a great chance to get duped vue package

I tried
"vue": "3.4.15",
"vue-router": "4.2.5"

And found differences in behavior but the problem with html comment and missing nodes still exists although the page gets further in loading.

Apparently, this was happening due to duplicated versions of Vue being loaded at the same time; Per the response here See I tried the latest version of vue-router@4.4.0 and had much more success.
